Noun clause or adjective clause?

His dream that he will be a doctor came true.

Here "that he will be a doctor" is which clause? Is it a noun clause or adjective clause?

"His dream that he would be a doctor" or, more idiomatically "of becoming a doctor".


His dream [that he would be a doctor] came true.

The declarative content clause (or that-clause) as bracketed functions as a complement of the head noun dream.
The same declarative content clause used in the following construction would be functioning as subject of the sentence:

[That he would be a doctor] came true.

In "His dream [of becoming a doctor] came true", the prepositional phrase functions as a complement to the head noun "dream" in the noun phrase structure.

I am afraid it is not a Relative clause. It is a Subordinate clause but it is a subordinate declarative clause. And it functions here as the complement of the the head noun "dream" inside the Noun Phrase structure.

Thanks, @Man_From_India.  I have edited my answer.

Thanks for your edit. But there are still some issues with the answer. In grammar there is a clear distinction between function and word class, and we need to respect that. Here in your answer this two seemed like similar. The fragment - that he will be a doctor - is a Declarative Content Clause (category) and it functions as a complement to the head noun. In your quoted sentence too it is a Declarative Content Clause and functions as a complement (here it is a Subject).

In "His dream of becoming a doctor came true." the Preposition Phrase "of becoming a doctor" is a Preposition Phrase (category) and functions as a complement to the head noun "dream" in the noun phrase structure - "his dream of becoming a doctor".

Thanks, @Man_From_India.  I have edited my answer.

I would avoid the term 'noun complement' since it implies that that he will be a doctor is a noun, which it isn't. The classification of finite subordinate clauses is based on their internal structure, not on spurious analogies with the parts of speech. @Man_From_India

@BillJ of course parts of speech and finite subordinate clause are different, but in my comment there I made it seem so. I meant it is just like a name. A category. Like a phrase, like a clause etc. yes based on their internal structure it is called finite subordinate clause. And I am also not ok with the term Noun complement.

OP's sentence:

His dream that he will be a doctor came true.

In the sentence "that he will be a doctor" is a restrictive relative (or adjective) clause as it is defining the noun "dream". Typically adjective clauses start with the relative pronouns - who, whose, whom, which and that. It defines or modifies a noun.
Suppose the sentence was :
His dream was that he will be a doctor..
In this case, the dependent clause is a noun clause and object of the sentence.
